# How do I get clang-format to align arguments in nested function calls by the root instead?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Using this minimal `.clang-format`:

```yaml
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 4
---
Language: Cpp
ColumnLimit: 120
UseTab: Never
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
ContinuationIndentWidth: 8
```

I end up with code formatted like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                      [](const std::string &) {
                          std::string x = "I'm here just to expand this block to keep it from collapsing";
                          return false;
                      }),
            vec.end());
    // the third argument, while invalid, doesn't affect clang-format.
    // It exists to force the lambda to break to the next line. If it
    // doesn't break, it ends up with slightly different, but still acceptable
    // formatting. I need it on a new line to demonstrate the difference between
    // a single function call, and calls to a function in the list of function
    // params
    std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), imasuperlonginvalididentifiertopushthisblockfaaaarofftotheleft,
            [](const std::string &) {
                std::string x = "I'm here just to expand this block to keep it from collapsing";
                return false;
            });
}
```

My problem here is with the first block.

First of all, notice the second block. It indents the lambda, a wrapped arg, by 8 spaces. I'm fine with this. The first block, however, is bad:

[image: Image showing the first block misaligning with indent guidelines]

Here's a numbered indent to show the problem:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
          12345678[](const std::string &) {
                      std::string x = "I'm here just to expand this block to keep it from collapsing";
                      return false;
                  }),
        vec.end());
```

Note how the indent is aligned to the start of `std::remove_if`. Because `vec.erase(` doesn't work out as 8, this means the *entire* block gets misaligned. I can deal with it for arguments, but the effects on multi-line lambda is a problem. **This is how I want it to format**:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                [](const std::string &) {
                    std::string x = "I'm here just to expand this block to keep it from collapsing";
                    return false;
                }),
        vec.end());
```

And numbered:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
1234567812345678[](const std::string &) {
                    std::string x = "I'm here just to expand this block to keep it from collapsing";
                    return false;
                  }),
        vec.end());
```

And an image:

[image: Image showing the desired format with indent guidelines]

While writing this question, I've been a bit back and forth, because I'm not sure when it triggers. I cut down the column width to force `std::remove_if` to wrap:

```
std::remove(
        std::remove_if( ...
                [](...) { ...
```

it's suddenly fine, because remove_if has been aligned to an 8 block, which means the arguments are indented by 8 or 16 as well. However, with this code:

```
    randomFunctionCall(functionCall2(9,
            std::string{"I need args so I made some up. "
                        "clang-format should allow them"},
            42, anotherlongidentifier, weeeeeeeeeee));
```

the arguments for the inner function arguments are fine. Well, kinda. They indent by 8 instead of 16, but I can live with that. (For the record, 16 comes from a continuation indent of 8, two levels deep, or 2 * 8 = 16). Now, watch what happens if I add another argument to the `randomFunctionCall` instead of adding to `functionCall2`:

```
randomFunctionCall(functionCall2(9,
                           std::string{"I need args so I made some up. "
                                       "clang-format should allow them"},
                           42, anotherlongidentifier, weeeeeeeeeee),
        randoarg);
```

The inner arguments align to the function call + 8 instead of the root function call + 16. So the misalignment happens, at least as far as I can tell, when there's a function call that takes a function call with arguments, but also has additional arguments beyond the function call.

When I have nested function calls (`func(func2(severalArgsWithLongEnoughNamesToWrap), nonfuncarg)`) with arguments, how do I get clang format to consider indentation from the start of the line, rather than from the start of the current function call? I'm aware I can use `// clang-format off/on` to locally enforce a non-standard style, but I would prefer not to.

I'm using Clang and clang-format 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: `AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent` (clang-format 14+) or `AlwaysAlign` on a technicality, but it doesn't always work because both rely on content length. Other newline-based approaches that exist now or in the future also work, but there are no config options for fixing the root cause. The root cause is that continuation indents are based on the immediate parent function, and not the total level of nesting.

---

Consider a modified example from clang-format's [documentation on ContinuationIndentWidth](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#continuationindentwidth), with `ContinuationIndentWidth: 1` for science:

```
int ifdsfds =    //  VeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment
 longFunction(   // Again a long comment
  longInnerFunc( // comment
   arg));
```

Adding a second argument doesn't do help much:

```
int ifdsfds =    //  VeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment
 longFunction(   // Again a long comment
  longInnerFunc( // comment
   arg),
  arg2);
```

Everything is correct so far with the options I had set. But look at what happens if the second comment disappears:

```
int ifdsfds =                //  VeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment
 longFunction(longInnerFunc( // comment
               arg),
  arg2);
```

Suddenly, the continuation indent is relative to its parent function rather than the root. This primarily happens when `arg2` is present, presumably because of context stuff? I'm not entirely sure, but take a look at `AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent`, which produces this (with `ContinuationIndentWidth: 4`):

```
vec.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        vec.begin(), vec.end(),
        [](const std::string &) {
            std::string x = "I'm here just to expand this block to keep it from collapsing";
            return false;
        }
    ),
    vec.end()
);
```

I assume this is the case for the previous example as well; when the comment was removed and `longInnerFunction` was collapsed onto its own line, the fact the argument was secretly indented relative to the root just became painfully visible. In fact, I believe most of the indentation (at least in this case) works relative to the immediate parent, with whatever changes propagating down to further sub-nodes.

This is also why `AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent` works. Its more aggressive newline system forces the functions onto their own lines. Here's another example of code formatted with `BlockIndent`:

```
someFunction(
    foooooooo(aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa),
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
);
```

Because the entire argument list is too long to fit within the `ColumnLimit`, the function is broken onto its new line. If you add a few more characters to the inner function's arguments (or to the function name), its arguments will be pushed onto a new line, and that line is indented `ContinuationIndentWidth` relative to `foooooooo`, which itself is intended `ContinuationIndentWidth` relative to `someFunction`.

In general, as long as each level of nested function calls is on its own line, the indents work as expected, because there isn't a need to add additional spaces to align with a given function call. `BlockIndent` forces newlines to keep the entire block `IndentWidth`-compliant. Mostly.

There are exceptions, such as this:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::string &) {
              std::string x = "I'm here just to expand this block to keep it from collapsing";
              return false;
          }), );
```

where the contents of the lambda are indented relative to the parent function via the indent mechanic I've explained in this answer. There isn't enough content in this case to trigger `BlockIndent`. This can be worked around by adding `//` after either `vec.begin()` or `vec.end()` to prevent block collapse.

`AlwaysBreak` is also a solution here, but one I didn't initially consider because I'm not entirely a fan of the formatting style it introduces, especially when it's asymmetric on which bracket is placed on a new line. That's just me though.

Anyway, for the time being at best and permanently at worst, `BlockIndent` is a partial solution. `AlwaysBreak`, in spite of its name, isn't any better, because it still only breaks if the width limit is hit. Both of them are effectively workarounds, and they do work better if combined with empty comments to keep linebreaks, but they're not a true solution.

I assume there's a way to force linebreaks as well, but I've spent too much time on this already to go looking, so this is left as an exercise to the reader with an above-average interest in lots of newlines.

In either case, the config option to base continuation indent on some sanely picked root (that isn't the immediate parent for nested function calls, and it'll still have to be automatically determined by clang-format) does not currently exist, and I'm not convinced there's enough demand for one for it to be available on any finite timescale. This leaves the workaround, or just switching to another solution, and I personally opted for the latter. A couple lines of `cino` config in Vim formats the code mostly good, but it makes up for it in requiring significantly less time to configure stuff.